# Installing app on Blackberry Playbook Simulator, from Flash Builder 4.5

Tags: blackberry-playbook

Deployment failed: 1
Error: Cannot connect: Connection to https://192.168.79.131 refused. Please check IP address settings for the target. You may have to reboot the target.

My app deploys fine in Air, but I can't get it to push to the simulator. Whenever it gets to the point where it tries to install the app, I get the above error. I've checked and made sure that the IP adress is correct. I've searched high and low on the internet, and nothing I've found has worked. So, if anyone has any ideas how I can install the app on the simulator please let me know. By the way, it used to work fine with Burrito, if that means anything. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **ping 192.168.79.131**

And checked there is no firewall rule preventing access to that IP address from your host (i.e. PC)?

Comment: Interesting I pinged the IP using command prompt and got the following message:
Pinging 192.168.79.131 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.79.131:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)

But I turned off all of the firewalls from my Norton Internet Security. Is there something else that might be blocking it? Thank you :)

Comment: Do you run any VMs on that PC?

Comment: I faced the same error/problem. if anything has helped you to solve this, it will be a pleasure to hear it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your PlayBook is on the same networks as your PC.
if your PlayBook is 192.168.79.131, your PC migh be 192.168.79.xxx, else you wont access it.

Comment: Hey sorry it's taken so long to get back to you guys, been busy with other work. So, guy who answered above, are you saying that if it's not on the same network then I can't access it? Or, if it IS on the same network, I won't be able to access it?

Comment: make sure your playbook is on the same network( or choose the same ip scheme ) as your testing PC. It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to do is change your network settings of your vmware to use a bridged network instead of NAT.
Shutdown the simulator and then locate the settings option. Under network settings select bridged. Resart the simulator. refer the below link

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Deployment-setup-wizard-issue/m-p/1388315#M173